Sets and Constrains in Pyomo
I have the following problem:
I would like to define multiple Constraint in Pyomo.
I have an indexed Set, where every row has an index (1,2,3..n_generators) and they corresponds to different time intervals (ex: row 1: [1,2,3,4,5], row 2: [3,4,5,6,7])
m.t = pyomo.Set(m.n_generators, initialize = bound_obj_t.bounds_rule_t)

now i would like to define the following constraint:
m.t[i][j-m.t[i][1]+1] >= ((m.tstart[i]-1)*self.T+1) - (self.time_tot+1)*(1-m.x[i,j])

so I have defined this function:
def m_init_rule(self, m, i,j):  
    return m.t[i][j-m.t[i][1]+1] >= ((m.tstart[i]-1)*self.T+1) - (self.time_tot+1)*(1-m.x[i,j]) 

I would like to pass the inputs so that "i" is the index (1,2,3 ecc) and "j" are the elements in the "i"'th row. (ex if "i" ==2 ==> it iterates over [3,4,5,6,7]). I menage to iterate over the indexes but no over the rows:
m.InitConstr = pyomo.Constraint(m.n_generators, m.t[1], rule=constr_obj.m_init_rule)

this one works, but every time it takes as time step only the first row. I would like to iterate over the current "i".
Can you please help me ?
m.InitConstr = pyomo.Constraint(m.n_generators, m.t[1], rule=constr_obj.m_init_rule)

this one works, but every time it takes as time step only the first row. I would like to iterate over the current "i".

The concept you are looking for is "indexed sets".  Take a look at these examples:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73996930/using-discontinuous-indices-for-pyomo-optimization/73997720#73997720, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73162186/pyomo-create-a-constraint-based-on-an-indexed-set/73169930#73169930
